# What is the best way to print a multidimensional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I recently started mutltidimensional int arrays in java. Before that one dimensional arrays had sufficed.

To print those I used `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myarray));`

But it won't work with multi dimensional arrays, it does the same thing as it does when you try to print a one dimensional array directly only many times.

Comment: Iterate through each dimension and use `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: `Arrays.deepToString()` is better though

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but it gave me everything in one line, which made it hard to read.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Can I iterate through the second dimension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to iterate through it.

The easiest way to do so is to use the provided [`Arrays.deepToString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) which searches for arrays within the array. Note that it, like Arrays.toString(), is only available in Java 1.5+ although I certainly hope that you are using Java 5 by now.

For example:

```
int[][] myArray = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
```

Alternatively, you can iterate yourself which also allows for more customization with the style in which you choose to print.

For example:

```
int[][] myArray = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
for(int[] arr : myArray)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: don't you have to put brackets after myArray?

Comment: @omnitic I'm not sure what you mean. Did I make a typo?

Comment: Upvoted, but I would reverse the order of the two parts of this answer -- mention `Arrays.deepToString` first, since for most cases it's probably preferable.

Comment: I preferred iterating myself since deep gave me everything in one line

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
int number[][] = { {1, 2, 3}, {1}, {2}};
for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Commons Lang 3's [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) toString method:

```
   @Test
   public void multiArrayToString(){
      int[] a = {1,2,3};
      int[] b = {4,5,6};
      int[][] c = {a, b};
      String aCommonsLangToString = ArrayUtils.toString(a);
      String bCommonsLangToString = ArrayUtils.toString(b);
      String cCommonsLangToString = ArrayUtils.toString(c);
      System.out.println(aCommonsLangToString);
      System.out.println(bCommonsLangToString);
      System.out.println(cCommonsLangToString);
   }
```

Output:

```
{1,2,3}
{4,5,6}
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

Comment: Do we really need Commons Lang dependency for a simple method which Java already has?

Comment: Good point, the Arrays.deepToString() method would help without the extra dependency, as posed by @pbabcdefp above. Using this the last line of output would be `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily iterate trough the array like this:

```
if (yourArray != null) {
    // Where object type means the type of your array.
    for (ObjectType subArray : yourArray) {
        // If this method can't receive nulls, then validate that subArray isn't null
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray));
    }
}
```